# Unnecessary dot in Badge notification?

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, top-bar

[image]

> You've earned the "Popular Question" badge for How do I protect myself against cold weather on the surface?. See your profile.

The ?. is bugging me a lot. Can something be done about it?.

Comment: IMO, it's less that the dot is unnecessary than that the question name should be quoted, or italicized, or something along those lines.

Comment: Woo is me, I'm getting badges!

Comment: Yeah, the issue here is that the question title is immediately followed by a period, which looks funny when the question ends in a ?.

Answer (score 3):

The question title is now surrounded by quotes in this notification, making the punctuation less awkward:

[image: Popular question notification]

Comment: I have no idea when this was fixed, but I thought it worth having the update on record.